# send notification message to client

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table in server. I want to show a notification message in client when that table will update. How can i do that? excuse me because I'm beginner in SQL

Comment: Please always specify what platform you are working on and what implementation of SQL (mySQL, SQL server, .....)

Comment: sorry, your right. I work in windows application and Sql server 2005

Answer (score 1):

you can use triggers for that.. here some notes for triggers

SQL triggers

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafysqltrig.htm

Introduction to SQL Triggers

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-triggers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this kind of thing should not be done on the database layer, but on the application layer where the change is initiated.

The database server is not really equipped to do this. It doesn't have E-Mail capabilities, and it has no notification system like the kind you talk about.

Answer (score 1):

How about SQL2008 [**Query Notification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx)? This is something different than *Notification Services* which was removed in SQL 2008. Query Notification is basically creating SqlDependency Object in a client application with a SELECT Query and then the SQL 2008 server notifies when there was any change in THE query result. Here's some client side [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx) example.

I have never used this myself but am looking for a very minimalistic intranet chat client based on SQL database.

Happy coding.